# Using Reflection to log the Properties of a type

Tags: c#, reflection

I want a clear and efficient way to log the values of all properties of any type.

The use case is that I have a number of APIs where there may be any type of model that is being passed.

So my code is quickly becoming cluttered with logging statements.

I'm thinking of utilizing Reflection to help with this, but I've never used Reflection in production code before. and I'm concerned of any performance issues that may arise by doing this.

I've created this extension method to my custom logger where I pass the object that I want to log as a generic type T.

```cs
    public static class MyLoggerExtensions
    {
        public static void AddObject<T>(this IMyLogger logger, T obj)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            properties
                .Where(p => p.CanRead)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(p =>
                    logger.AddProperty(p.Name, p.GetValue(obj).ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Please tell me if this use of reflection has the potential to degrade performance of my APIs?

Comment: It depends how you define "degrade performance". It takes time to run that code, of course, but I doubt you will be able to measure a difference unless test it under load.

Comment: `Please tell me if this use of reflection has the potential to degrade performance of my APIs?` It has the potential, yes. But you should test it - that is the only way to know for sure. Have you considered converting the object to JSON instead?

Comment: The `.ToList()` is definitely not needed. Remove it and the `ForEach` and use a standard `foreach` loop.

Comment: https://theburningmonk.com/2015/08/fasterflect-vs-hyperdescriptor-vs-fastmember-vs-reflection/ may also be worth a read.

Comment: Rather than looking everything up every time, create a  dictionary (or a list of key value pairs) of property names (as the key) and getter `MethodInfo`s for each type you see. Cache that dictionary for the type. That way, the next time you need to log something for the type, the expensive part of the reflection is already done.

Comment: Your question is overly broad. But, for maximum performance you want run-time-compiled code to access the properties. You can use expressions to build and compile dynamic methods for the property retrieval, then memoize (store in a dictionary based on type and property name) the delegates compiled from those expressions so you only get the perf hit the first time you log the value. Logging is slow anyway, so the one-time impact per property shouldn't be too bad. See marked duplicate.